# VPN with a web API to switch locations

Tags: api, vpn

The VPNs I have used so far offer a button or a list, where you can choose from where you want your VPN to operate. For example, I could choose France, and then I get a French IP address.

I am looking for a VPN service which offers a web API to switch the location from which I'm operating. I.e. there should be an endpoint like

```
https://mysupervpn.com/api/switchlocation?location=fr
```

When this endpoint is invoked (via the VPN), then the VPN switches to a location in France, until the same endpoint is invoked with a different parameter. The endpoint should do the exact same work as the "Switch Location" button of the other VPNs.

Is there a VPN which offers such a functionality?